# JavaScript redirect containing '#'

Tags: javascript, redirect

I am in a page with location 'www.something.com#tab2'
Now there is a button in this #tab2. I want to refresh to that same location 'www.something.com#tab2' when I press the button on that page. How can I do that? I tried the normal window.location.href = "www.something.com#tab2" but it doesnt work.

Comment: `window.location.reload();` should work

Comment: @KIMB-technologies no it doesnt work.

Answer (score 0):

This isn't as easy as it sounds.  You need to grab that URL fragment out of the URL with JS and take action accordingly like:

```
 var fragment= window.location.hash.substring(1);
 showTab(fragment);
```

where showTab() reveals the appropriate tab / item maybe like:

```
function showTab(fragment) {
    if (fragment) {
        $('.tab').hide();
        $('#' + showId).show();
    }
}
```

Personally, if I'm doing something like this where I need to remember a tab's state, I prefer to save that tab's state in a cookie every time the user clicks a tab and have the server check for that cookie and render the page accordingly.